# After setting up multisite on localhost, requests to localhost redirect to production domain

Tags: multisite, directory

After setting up multisite on http://localhost, requests to http://localhost redirect to http://production-domain.com (Including "Log In").

- Where is the production domain information even being retrieved from?
- I suspect the cause is modifications to wp-config.php or .htaccess files. If I revert these changes, the site works again properly (albeit without multisite)

---

**More detailed symptoms:**

**The WordPress site itself stops loading properly.** When loading http://localhost:

- Before multisite

  - All html and assets requested from http://localhost as expected.
- After multisite

  - Html and some assets loaded from http://localhost, but most CSS and images are requested from http://production-server.com

**Log In is also affected:**

- Before multisite:

  1. Load http://localhost/wp-admin/
  2. Redirected to http://localhost/wp/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http://localhost/wp/wp-admin/&reauth=1
  3. (Log In page is styled correctly.)
- After multisite:

  1. Load http://localhost/wp-admin/
  2. Redirected to  http://www.production-domain.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http://localhost/wp/wp-admin/&reauth=1
  3. (Log In page is missing styling because css fails to load from http://www.production-domain.com.)

---

**How I configured multisite.:**

**Added following lines to c:/www/wp/wp-config.php:**

```
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );

define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'localhost');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/'); // Also tried: define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/wp/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

**(Already had this in /www/wp/wp-config.php:)**

```
// Overwrites the database to save from constantly editing the DB
define('WP_HOME','http://localhost/');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost/wp');
```

**c:/www/.htaccess:**

```
# Original version left as comments at bottom.
# Note WordPress is installed in the wp subdirectory
# so there is another file, c:/www/wp/.htaccess
# which I have tried both editing and leaving intact.


RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) wp/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ wp/$2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

# <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# RewriteEngine On
# RewriteBase /
# RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
# </IfModule>
#
# # BEGIN WordPress
# <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# RewriteEngine On
# RewriteBase /wp/
# RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
# </IfModule>
#
# # END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1):

OK. I figured it out: **When moving to multisite, manually overriding WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL like below doesn't work anymore:**

```
// Overwrites the database to save from constantly editing the DB
define('WP_HOME','http://localhost');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost/wp');
```

I fixed this by manually changing the database so WP_HOME is http://localhost and WP_SITEURL is http://localhost/wp.